# Java class is despite new ...; not called up

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I have a problem with call up a class. I'm programming in Eclipse and I have another Java Program, which works very well, but I can't see any difference. Here is the code of the Main class:

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                new Var();
                new GUI();
                new Label();
                new ActionHandler();
        }
}
```

If I place a `System.out.println("Test");`in the Label class, I don't get the output.
Here is the Label class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Label extends JLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g.drawImage(Var.ibackground, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, null);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Lupus

Comment: Where in the `Label` class do you put the print? All you're doing here is creating a new instance, then discarding it. You'd only see that `print` if it's in the constructor.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label object is definitely created,  but since it is not added to GUI view hierarchy it will be never used -  so nobody is going to call paintComponent() on it

Comment: exactly, but I think you need to clarify for @Lupus Prime, that he need to call `frameObject.add(new Label())`

Comment: goot point.      I would suggeest taking basic  tutorial on  Swing to gain understanding how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had copied the basic lines from another project to save some time, then I apparently deleted the label because of non-existent variables. The program works now.